# Android google plus sign in error when login onemore

Tags: android, google-plus, android-googleapiclient

I have login google plus, but when i login success, and in the new activity, i logout,after i login again,it is not success login.
Log:**ClearcutLoggerApiImpl: disconnect managed GoogleApiClient**

It is code:

```
GoogleSingleton:
public class GoogleSingleton {
    private ILogInGoogleListener mListener = null;

    public void setLogInGooglePlusListener(final ILogInGoogleListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ILogInGoogleListener {
        void logInGooglePlusSuccess(String name,
                                    String email,
                                    String pid);
    }

    private static GoogleSingleton googleSingleton;
    private final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 321;
    private Activity activity;

    private GoogleSingleton(final Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                                   .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onConnected(final Bundle bundle) {
                                           try {
                                               if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                                                   System.out.println(">>>> Log in xong");
                                                   Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                                                                                  .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                                                   String personName =
                                                           currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                                                   String email =
                                                           Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                                                   String id = currentPerson.getId();
                                                   if (mListener != null) {
                                                       mListener.logInGooglePlusSuccess(personName,
                                                                                        email,
                                                                                        id);
                                                   }

                                               }
                                           } catch (Exception e) {
                                               e.printStackTrace();
                                           }
                                           // Update the UI after signin
                                       }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onConnectionSuspended(final int i) {
                                           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                           System.out.println(">>>> chua log in");
                                       }
                                   })
                                   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult result) {
                                           if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                               GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                                                                     activity,
                                                                                     0)
                                                                     .show();
                                           }
                                           mConnectionResult = result;
                                       }
                                   })
                                   .addApi(Plus.API)
                                   .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                                   .build();
    }

    public static GoogleSingleton getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (googleSingleton == null) {
            googleSingleton = new GoogleSingleton(activity);
        }
        return googleSingleton;
    }

    public void connectGoogle() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void disConnectGoogle() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public boolean isConnecting() {
        return mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
    }

    public void login() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> check login Singleton");
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            if (mConnectionResult != null && mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>> check login Singleton Try:" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() + "__" + mConnectionResult.hasResolution());

                try {
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                                                               RC_SIGN_IN);
                    System.out.println(">>>>>> abce");

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(">>>>>> check login Singleton:" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() + "__" + mConnectionResult.hasResolution());
        }
    }

    public void logOut() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            //set text button google plus.
        }
    }
}
```

Activity 1: 
LogIn:

```
 /**
 * init google plus.
 * - init api client.
 * - fill data when success.
 * - set text when login success.
 */
private void initGooglePlus() {
    GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                   .connectGoogle();
    GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                   .setLogInGooglePlusListener(new GoogleSingleton.ILogInGoogleListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void logInGooglePlusSuccess(final String name,
                                                          final String email,
                                                          final String pid) {
                           System.out.println(">>>>> check name:"+name);
                           logInGooglePlus(name,
                                           email,
                                           pid);
                       }
                   });
}

  /**
 * - Sign in google.
 * - check null button,and check have sign in.
 * - when logout,set data model user local empty.
 * - if have sign in, click sign out,reverse.
 *
 * @param view
 *         This is button google.
 */
@OnClick(R.id.btnDangNhapGoogle)
protected void setOnDangNhapClicked(View view) {
    //sign in and sign out google.
    if (btnDangNhapGooglePlus != null) {
        //log out
        if (btnDangNhapGooglePlus.getText()
                                 .equals(getResources().getString(R.string.text_log_out))) {
            if (GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                               .isConnected()) {
                //Log out.
                GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                               .logOut();
                //set text button google plus.
                btnDangNhapGooglePlus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text_dang_nhap_bang_google_plus));
                //set null user model.
                LocalStorage.getShareInstance(SignInActivity.this)
                            .saveUserModel(new UserModel());
            }
        }//log in
        else {
            if (!GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                                .isConnecting()) {
                GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                               .login();

            }
        }
    }


}

/**
 * - activity result of facebook, google plus.
 * - when logout from account activity, logout all social, and set local data user empty.
 *
 * @param requestCode
 *         This is request.
 * @param resultCode
 *         This is result.
 * @param data
 *         This is data.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                final int resultCode,
                                final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,
                           resultCode,
                           data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,
                                      resultCode,
                                      data);
    System.out.println(">>>>>> connect requecode"+requestCode);
    if (requestCode == GoogleSingleton.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> connect RC_SIGN_IN");
        if (!GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                            .isConnecting()) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>> connect vvvvv");
            mIsCheckLoginGoogle = true;
            GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                           .connectGoogle();
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOGOUT_ALL) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> check result logout code");
        logOutFaceBookAndGooglePlusResult();
        //set null user model.
        LocalStorage.getShareInstance(SignInActivity.this)
                    .saveUserModel(new UserModel());
    }
}

/**
 * - check facebook and google plus.
 * - logout facebook and google plus.
 * - set text google plus.
 */
private void logOutFaceBookAndGooglePlusResult() {
    if (GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                       .isConnected()) {
        GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this)
                       .logOut();
        //set text button google plus.
        btnDangNhapGooglePlus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text_dang_nhap_bang_google_plus));
    }
    //log out facebook.
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance()
                    .logOut();
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
 //init google connect.
    GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this).connectGoogle();
//logout google.
        GoogleSingleton.getInstance(this).logOut();
```

Comment: This is a story, what is your question?

Comment: why are i login no success when i log out.